# Who was Captain Hastel?

Tags: poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire, alaksiej-zarycki

*The Eagle Well-Spring* by Alaksiej Zarycki was dedicated "to the memory of Captain Hastel."

It includes the lines

> ... For the eagle's grave came not seeking!
> That's where Hastel's heart ceased, no more to
> Beat after all its striving - men tell it -
> On that spot there flows, ever-pouring
> From the plumbless depths, a clear well-spring

Who was Captain Hastel, and why was the poem dedicated to him?

Comment: with greatest possibility - [this hero of the soviet union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Gastello). Sorry, no answer from me.